# Return an object from a class to a form

Tags: c#

I have this object which I pass to a function call import through a constructor that is no problem to understand.

```
public class ErrorObject
{
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string SupplierAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountCostCentre { get; set; }
    public string AccountDepartment { get; set; }
    public bool IsInvalidSupplier { get; set; }
    public bool IsInvalidNominal { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I have here a sample of how I pass it and reuse I in the class called Import which is called from Program .cs

```
List<ErrorObject> erorObjects = new List<ErrorObject>();
public ImportEngine(List<ErrorObject> _errors)
{
    erorObjects = _errors;
}
```

I call the import engine as such this could be inside  a form load event for example

```
ImportEngine import = new ImportEngine(erorObjects);
```

Once the `ImportEngine` class has finished with the object, how do I return it to the calling instance so I can process it again in my form?

Do I simply have the property public and reference it when I return to my calling function?

Comment: For example, yes.

Comment: As a side note from a code style standpoint if you are going to use an underscore prefix for a variable, you generally use that for private member variables and not for a local and method arguments.

Comment: _"how do I return it to the calling instance so I can process it again in my form?"_ -- why do you need to do that? The calling instance passed it to the class in the first place. They already have the reference. They should just keep the reference. Why do you think anything more is needed? I don't really understand your question, or if I do, there are so many different ways to address it (including, essentially, doing nothing special) that it's way too broad. Please be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` is a [Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data. With reference types, two variables can reference the same object; therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable.

Because `ImportEngine.errorObjects` references the same list that you pass it you shouldn't have to do anything; whatever you do to `ImportEngine.errorObjects` will also be done on the list that you passed it since they're both references to the same list. This is provided that you don't assign `ImportEngine.errorObjects` to a different list during the lifetime of the `ImportEngine` instance.

But, if you did need to get the list back from `ImportEngine` then a public property would be one way to do it.